# Installing jQuery API Browser AIR

Tags: jquery, api, adobe, air

Can someone tell me how to install this? I go here: http://api.jquery.com/browser/ and click the **INSTALL NOW** button. After that it says "Download and open the AIR file to begin the Installation".  I have AIR installed but can't figure out where the file is for the API Browser.

I'm definitely missing something obvious...

Comment: no, its not obvious. i had the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the closest thing I could find was a link here: http://remysharp.com/2008/07/04/jquery-api-update-offline-and-anywhere/

There's an offline AIR download, which I can't seem to find on the API browser website.

Comment: I am glad you got it solved. Once I realized I was off base I got distracted. My non-answer will self destruct in 5.4.3.2...

Answer (score 5):

here it's:

http://api.jquery.com/browser/update/jquery-api-browser-2.0.air